# How can I tell if my program is running on a Domain Controller?

Tags: c#

Using C# is there a way to tell if the computer my program is running on is a Domain Controller?

Comment: There's a network admin that allows your code to run on a DC?  Well, he could tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate DCs (snippet below from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#16)) - check for your server name in the resulting list:

```
public static ArrayList EnumerateDomainControllers()
{
    ArrayList alDcs = new ArrayList();
    Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
    foreach (DomainController dc in domain.DomainControllers)
    {
        alDcs.Add(dc.Name);
    }
    return alDcs;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully he is not talking about .NET 1.x.  If that is the case, I hope you replace ArrayList with List<string>.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter solution, just check the registry:

```
const string basename = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\";    
const string keyname = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\ProductOptions";
string result = (string) Registry.GetValue(basename + keyname, "ProductType", "WinNT");
```

If the result is "**WinNT**" it's a client machine. If it's "**ServerNT**", server, and "**LanmanNT**" is a Domain Controller.

More info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782360%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete function I came up with, to answer the question.

```
    public static bool ThisMachineIsADomainController()
    {
        Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();

        string thisMachine = String.Format("{0}.{1}",Environment.MachineName, domain.ToString());
        //Enumerate Domain Controllers
        List<string> allDcs = new List<string>();

        foreach (DomainController dc in domain.DomainControllers)
        {
            allDcs.Add(dc.Name);
        }
        return allDcs.Contains(thisMachine);
    }
```